# leitura/manipulação de imagens em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

- Utilizo o Windows 8.1 ( 64 bits );
- O Python 3.7, o Spyder 3 e a Biblioteca Scikit-Image, tudo incluído no pacote Anaconda.

Eis o super simples código:

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread("C:\Users\Vitor Monteiro\Pictures\Nova pasta\bull.jpg")
io.imshow(img)
io.show()
```

Eis os erros:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Vitor Monteiro/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Vitor Monteiro/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Vitor Monteiro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "<ipython-input-8-9f9680e460c7>", line 1, in <module>

runfile('C:/Users/Vitor Monteiro/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Vitor Monteiro/.spyder-py3')

File "C:\Users\Vitor Monteiro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Vitor Monteiro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Vitor Monteiro/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 6
img = io.imread("C:\Users\Vitor Monteiro\Pictures\Nova pasta\bull.jpg")
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Como são possiveis tantos erros em apenas 4 linhas de código?

Comment: Tem certeza que o seu código é somente isso? Pela mensagem de erro, o código `img = io.imread(...)` está na linha 6, mas o que nos apresentou estaria na linha 2.

Comment: Sim, o código é só mesmo aquele.

Comment: Eu gosto de deixar linhas vazias no principio, e o código começa portanto na linha 4.

Comment: Passei por um problema parecido,era porque tava passando uma string "bruta" no path, tenta usar `img = io.imread(r"C:\Users\Vitor Monteiro\Pictures\Nova pasta\bull.jpg")` pra converter pra uma raw string ;)